# Need help to extract a data with Label using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<ws:Address_Line_Data ws:PriorValue="" ws:Label="Address Line 1" ws:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1">8925 Lietner lWay</ws:Address_Line_Data>
<ws:Address_Line_Data ws:PriorValue="" ws:Label="Address Line " ws:Type="ADDRESS_LINE_2">#504</ws:Address_Line_Data>
```

I have two feed for the address. I need the value only with "label Address Line 1" also I need to normalize the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[normalize-space(@ws:Label) = 'Address Line 1']"/>
```

Comment: Hi Am a beginner in XSLT. Which resource is good to kick start XSLT

Comment: start at [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp) later for more details visit [World Wide Consortium W3C](https://www.w3.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ws:Address_Line_Data[@ws:Label='Address Line 1'])" />
```